# How to execute something that is not in the directory you are in nor a sub-directory of that?

Tags: command-line, paths, execute-command

I want to execute a program by running `./path/to/program`, however I want to be able to run this command to execute it no matter where I am. And the problem is that with this command it will only run the program if I am in its directory (and just execute the program with `./program`) or if the path I give to it is leading through the sub-directories of the currently directory that I am in.

So for instance I want to be able to run `./usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans` when I am in my `~` and have it run the program at `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans`, rather than it trying to run `~/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans` if such a path exists.

So is there any way for me to do this? I understand that I am using the `.` node. And I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Why don't you just use `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans` if you want to run that file?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: Oh! I didn't know I could do that! Can you please convert that into and answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as removing the dot.

You can always run a program by typing the path to it.

If you type: `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans`

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans
```

will be executed, no matter your working directory. The path is not relative, because it begins with a `/`.

`./program` executes 'program' in the directory you're in. The `.` meaning current directory.

The reason you can't just type 'program', is a 'safety' mechanism. For instance someone could have named a malicious file 'ls' and you could risk running that malicious application instead of ls if you were in the directory trying to view the content.